# ERC20 transfer function

Tags: solidity

i have write a ERC20 program and inside a add function to create a data base of people.
I upgrate every people who have some interaction with my website during 3 month and give us an amount of my token.
Token are blocked and distribuated at the end.
For this, i want that people reclame their token and call a function for this. i want they use transferfrom and approve but in a special function, who declare how much token they have win.
If i approve people will use the function transferfrom directly and may be forgot some token.

Have you idea?

```
function PostDelivery(string memory pseudo) public {
   require(isFinish);
   require(msg.sender == Database[pseudo].data_address);  
   require(Database[pseudo].payed == false;);   
   
   transferFrom(accountwithtoken,Database[pseudo].data_address,Database[pseudo].data_balance ) 
   Database[pseudo].payed = true;
   
}

function finish() public {
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    isFinish = true; 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better your problem? Please, if you can put an example

Comment: function withdraw() public {
    //i want each who call this function can take amount of my token he have win
  }